# how to do do line by line comparison of data of 2 files if if open files in binary in c?

Tags: c, file, data-structures, binary, fwrite

the question :-
In the file ‘CUSTOMER.DAT’ there are 100 records with the structure customer .In another file ‘TRANSACTIONS.DAT’ there are several records with the structure trans

The element trans_type contains D/W indicating deposit or withdrawal of amount. Write a program to update ‘CUSTOMER.DAT’ file, i.e., if the trans_type is ‘D’ then update the balance of ‘CUSTOMER.DAT’ by adding amount to balance for the corresponding accno. Similarly, if trans_type is ‘W’ then subtract the amount from balance.

I am able to compare line by line data in a file if i open file in txt mode i.e in "r" and "w" but when i open in binary "rb" "wb" ,i can't compare line by line data. How to do it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct customer
{
  int accno ;
  char name[30] ;
  float balance ;
};

struct trans
{
  int accnum ;
  char trans_type ;
  float amount ;
} ;


int main()
{
    FILE *fs,*ft,*f1;

    struct customer c;
    struct trans tr;

    fs = fopen("customer.txt","rb");

    if (fs==NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file.");
        exit(1);
    }

    f1 = fopen("transactions.txt","rb");

    if (f1==NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file.");
        exit(2);
    }


    ft = fopen("temp.txt","wb");

    if (ft==NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file.");
        exit(3);
    }

    while(fread(&c,sizeof(c),1,fs)==1)
    {
        while(fread(&tr,sizeof(tr),1,f1)==1)
        {
            if( tr.accnum == c.accno && tr.trans_type == 'D')
            {
                c.balance = c.balance + tr.amount;
                break;
            }

            else if( tr.accnum == c.accno && tr.trans_type == 'W')
            {
                if(c.balance - tr.amount < 100)
                    break;
                else
                    c.balance = c.balance - tr.amount;

                break;
            }
        }
        fwrite(&c,sizeof(c),1,ft);
    }
    fclose(fs);
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(ft);

    remove("customer.txt");
    rename("temp.txt","customer.txt");
    return 0;

}
```

The data sample in customer.txt is

1 aman 456.45

2 loma 199.40

3 shail 15

The data sample in transactions.txt is

1 D 500.89

3 W 51.00

2 W 40

where D is deposit and w is withdraw

Comment: You attempt to read raw binary structures. If the data in the files is plain text (as indicated by the `.txt` suffix) and not the raw structures you have defined in your program, that simply won't work.

Comment: Binary data has no concept of lines. Lines only exist in text files. You need to explain better your requirements. Usual definition of **line** is *sequence of characters terminated by, and [usually] including, a newline*. If you mean something different than this, you need to say what you mean by "line".

Comment: are you going to read all transactions for every customer? If so, you have to start from the beginning of the file each time. Else read all transactions and save them.

Comment: @pmg by line i mean data of  structure 'customer' like 1 pmg 405.00 which is accno , name and balance of a customer

Comment: @stark yes all transactions are compared for similar accno for each customer if matched balance is added or deducted according to data in transactions.txt file

Comment: @SupportUkraine by line by line i mean data of structure 'customer' like 1 pmg 405.00 which is accno , name and balance of a customer .it is saved in file customer.txt .Each line contains data of single customer.

Comment: Given the many possible attributes of _text_ mode: byte-order marks, line ending, file endings, the simplest was to read a file opened in binary in a line-by-line fashion is to re-open in text mode and use `fgets()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica   i have given sample of datat stored in both files ,take a look at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

File data is encoded as *text*.  Do not read the data  with `fread()` which expects a fixed length binary data.

Open the file in *text* mode and read the *line* of data with `fgets()`.

```
char buffer[100];
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fs)) {
  // Now process the data
```

Let us process the data with `sscanf()`.  Look for malformed data.  Use `" %n"` to record the offset of trailing non-white-space text.

```
  struct trans tr;
  int n = 0; 
  sscanf(buffer, "%d %c %f %n", &tr.accnum, &tr.trans_type, &tr.amount, &n);
  // Was scanning incomplete or extra junk at the end or non W,D?
  if (n == 0 || buffer[n] != 0 || 
      (tr.trans_type != 'W' && tr.trans_type != 'D')) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Bad input <%s>\n", buffer);
    break;
  }

  // Use `t`. 

}
```

When it is time to write, use sufficient precision to write a distinctive `float`.

```
 fpritnf(fs, "%d %c %.9g\n", t.accnum, t.trans_type, t.amount);
```